# RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #3 'index' in call to _th_index_select site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using the bert on the SMILE dataset. I have written following code can you guide me where I am getting wrong.
I have written training code which is evaluating correctly but the when I try to run evaluate code for validation it is giving error. I tried to pass the parameters directly to cuda. still I am facing the issue

```
'''

def evaluate(dataloader_val):

  print("in evaluate")
  model.eval()

  loss_val_total = 0
  predictions, true_value = [],[]

  for batch in dataloader_val:

    print("in for loop of dataloader")
    barch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

    inputs = {
               'input_ids':  batch[0],
                'attention_mask': batch[1],
                 'labels' : batch[2],
    }

    with torch.no_grad():
      outputs = model(**inputs)

    loss = outputs[0]
    logits = outputs[1]
    loss_val_total += loss.item()

    print("before logit")

    logits = logits.to(device)
    print("in the for batch evaluate: ",logits)
    label_ids = inputs['labels'].to(device)
    true_vals.append(label_ids)

  loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val)

  predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis = 0)
  true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals,axis = 0)

  return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals
'''
```

and another function is

```
'''
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
  model.train()

  loss_train_total = 0

  progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train,
                      desc = 'Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch),
                      leave = False,
                      disable = False)
  for batch in progress_bar:

    model.zero_grad()

    batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

    inputs = {

            'input_ids'      : batch[0],
            'attention_mask' : batch[1],
            'labels'         : batch[2]
    }

    outputs = model(**inputs)

    loss = outputs[0]
    loss_train_total += loss.item()
    loss.backward()

    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()

    progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss' : '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})

  torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'/content/drive/My Drive/Bert/Coursera/SMILE/Bert_ft_epoch{epoch}.model')

  tqdm.write(f'\n Epoch {epoch}')

  loss_train_avg = loss_train_total / len(dataloader_train)

  tqdm.write(f'Training Loss: {loss_train_avg}')

  val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_val)
  val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
  tqdm.write(f'Validation loss : {val_loss}')
  tqdm.write(f'F1 score(weighted): {val_f1}')
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your evaluation function:

```py
barch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
```

You assign the gpu data to `barch` instead of `batch`.